# How to check given string date is my dd-mm-yyyy format in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

My date format is dd-mm-yyyy. there is a string date I want to check that string date is 'dd-mm-yyyy' if not( like dd/mm/yyyy, 10-OCT-2013) that function will return 'NO'

```
function checkMydateFormat(checkDate IN VARCHAR)VARCHAR{

IF(check date is 'dd-mm-yyyy')THEN
  RETURN 'YES';
ELSE
  RETURN 'NO';
END IF;

}
```

How can I write a PL/SQL function to check string date is correct format?

Comment: use FORMAT(Now(),'YYYY-MM-DD') to check date format

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to test if date format string is a valid date format string in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979654/how-to-test-if-date-format-string-is-a-valid-date-format-string-in-oracle)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
var par varchar2(20);
exec :par := '17-10-2013';
DECLARE
FUNCTION checkMydateFormat(checkDate IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2 IS RESULT VARCHAR2(10);
  BEGIN
    SELECT CASE
             WHEN regexp_like('7-10-2013', '\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{4}\', 'i') THEN
              'yes'
             ELSE
              'no'
           END into RESULT
      FROM dual;
    RETURN(RESULT);
  END checkMydateFormat;


BEGIN
  dbms_output.enable(NULL);
  dbms_output.put_line(checkMydateFormat(:par));

END;
```

Comment: WRONG.you did not bind the variable used, and the logic is wrong  , as it return 'YES' for '99-99-9999' too.:)

Comment: regexlike works for me like this : 
if regexlike(value,'99.99') then
 //statements
end if :)

Answer (score 1):

you can try to convert the string to the date using the desired format, and catch Exceptions. Somthing like the following:

```
create function checkMydateFormat(checkDate IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  v_result VARCHAR2(3);
  v_date    DATE;
BEGIN 
  BEGIN 
    v_date  := to_date(checkDate,'fxdd-mm-yyyy');
    v_result := 'YES';
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN v_result := 'NO'; 
  END;
  RETURN v_result;
END;
/
```

Comment: You don't need the interior begin and end and this will throw an error if the date is in the correct format...

Comment: how can be 'YES' be saved in a datatype of varchar(2)?

Comment: It may return `yes` even if date string literal is of wrong format. For instance `10-OCT-2013`, but date format model clearly states that the month should be represented by two digits. To enforce exact matching between character date literal format model add `FX` format model modifier. (`'fxdd-mm-yyyy'`)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION checkMydateFormat(
          checkDate IN VARCHAR2)
     RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
     v_result VARCHAR2(3);
     v_date   DATE;
BEGIN
     v_date   := to_date(checkDate,'fxdd-mm-yyyy');
     V_RESULT := 'YES';
     RETURN V_RESULT;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
     V_RESULT := 'NO';
     RETURN v_result;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace function checkMydateFormat(checkDate IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  v_date    DATE;
BEGIN 
    v_date  := to_date(checkDate,'dd-mm-yyyy');
    RETURN 'YES';
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN 
    RETURN 'NO'; 
END checkMydateFormat;
```